# Design patterns for shape construction

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm new to the design patterns and I need help to decide which patterns to use on my app.

The task is to write a simple console version of a drawing program, so if you insert:

**C** - Should create a new **canvas** of width w and height h

**L** - Should create a new **line** **R** - Should create a new **rectangle** **Q** - Should **quit** the program

So I have thought about using two design patterns. **Abstract Factory** for the commands and **Decorator** for the shapes. Is this the correct approach? or do you guys recommend using something else?

Comment: Generally, the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern works well for most GUI applications.  Since this is a console application, the pattern will be a bit more difficult to apply.  Create a logical model to hold lines and rectangles.  Both lines and rectangles can be defined with two points.  You can use a java.awt.Point to hold a point.  Your view draws on the console based on the logical model.

Comment: A sequential set of steps makes me think of the builder pattern